# how to retrieve an xml file from azure blob storage using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to retrieve 2 Xml file from an Blob storage and return those file using c#. No worries about the connection, container name and file name.
I tried below code to get the xml as a string from the blob and return as a list but I need an to return as a Xmlfile.

```
 public List<string> GetXmlFiles(List<string> Xmlname)
        {
            string storageConnectionString = "";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("fileName");
            string xml =blob.DownloadTextAsync().ToString();
            List<string> XmlFile = new List<string>(xml.Split(' '));
        
            return XmlFile;

            }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code , I tested in my system able to download the xml file as file

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace downloadxml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string storageConnectionString = "Connection string”
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            var allblobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
            List<String> files = new List<String>();
            foreach (var blob in allblobs)
            {
                string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)blob).Name;
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
                string path = (@"localk path”)
                string[] names = name.Split("/");
                string newPath = "";
                string fileName = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i != (names.Length - 1))
                    {
                        path = path + names[i] + "\\";
                        newPath = newPath + "\\" + names[i];
                    }
                    fileName = names[(names.Length - 1)];
                }
                string filePath = path + fileName;
                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                }
             files.Add(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

I have  two xml file `xmlfile1` and `xmlfile2`

[image]

Downloded both files as `xmlfile1` and `xmlfile2` as xml document locally

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not want to download it. I want to return those 2 Xml as a file in the function

Comment: both 2 xml as single file?

Comment: no 2 xml as seperate file

Comment: as your requirement you need to return 2 files ,without saving the  file you can't return the files so ,I edited answer like downloading files and adding the both files to String list,So you can return both files path in your function

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you